# Bluestack is not able to show local server on webview in android

Tags: android, webview, bluestacks, localserver

I am trying to access the local server which is running on my system from my application running on Bluestack through WebView but is shows the blank white screen. Following is the URL http://192.168.0.85:8080/WRA.
This URL is working fine from the mobile phone if I connect to mobile with the same network but it is not working on bluestack.
Here is the logcat.

```
     01-13 16:20:18.350 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel V/WebViewChromium: Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {32774c14}
    01-13 16:20:18.350 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
    01-13 16:20:18.350 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel I/BrowserProcessMain: Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
    01-13 16:20:18.350 4478-4774/com.workstream.squirrel W/chromium: [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
    01-13 16:20:18.360 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/PGA: [4478] egl: eglDestroySurface (0x5578a7a0, 0x78506710)
    01-13 16:20:18.360 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/PGA: [4478] egl: eglDestroySurface (0x5578a7a0, 0x78506710) returned
    01-13 16:20:18.370 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceRequest;)
    01-13 16:20:18.370 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceError;)
    01-13 16:20:18.370 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.webkit.WebViewClient.onReceivedError, referenced from method com.workstream.squirrel.views.Profile$Browser.onReceivedError
    01-13 16:20:18.370 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10926: Landroid/webkit/WebViewClient;.onReceivedError (Landroid/webkit/WebView;Landroid/webkit/WebResourceRequest;Landroid/webkit/WebResourceError;)V
    01-13 16:20:18.370 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
    01-13 16:20:18.410 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/PGA: [4478] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x5578a7a0, 0x0, 0x7857b968, 0x775590e0)
    01-13 16:20:18.410 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/PGA: [4478] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x5578a7a0, 0x0, 0x7857b968, 0x775590e0) returned
    01-13 16:20:18.420 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
    01-13 16:20:18.450 4478-4786/com.workstream.squirrel I/chromium: [INFO:simple_index_file.cc(397)] Simple Cache Index is being restored from disk.
    01-13 16:20:18.460 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
    01-13 16:20:18.490 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/PGA: [4478] egl: eglDestroySurface (0x5578a7a0, 0x78489620)
    01-13 16:20:18.490 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/PGA: [4478] egl: eglDestroySurface (0x5578a7a0, 0x78489620) returned
    01-13 16:20:18.870 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_CULL_FACE, assuming size 1
    01-13 16:20:18.870 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_CULL_FACE, assuming size 1
    01-13 16:20:18.880 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_DITHER, assuming size 1
    01-13 16:20:18.880 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_DITHER, assuming size 1
    01-13 16:20:18.930 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
    01-13 16:20:18.980 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
    01-13 16:20:19.100 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_CULL_FACE, assuming size 1
    01-13 16:20:19.100 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_CULL_FACE, assuming size 1
    01-13 16:20:19.110 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_DITHER, assuming size 1
    01-13 16:20:19.110 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_DITHER, assuming size 1
    01-13 16:20:19.220 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_CULL_FACE, assuming size 1
    01-13 16:20:19.220 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_CULL_FACE, assuming size 1
    01-13 16:20:19.230 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_DITHER, assuming size 1
    01-13 16:20:19.230 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_DITHER, assuming size 1
```

.

```
01-13 16:20:18.350 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel V/WebViewChromium: Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {32774c14}
01-13 16:20:18.350 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
01-13 16:20:18.350 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel I/BrowserProcessMain: Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
01-13 16:20:18.350 4478-4774/com.workstream.squirrel W/chromium: [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
01-13 16:20:18.360 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/PGA: [4478] egl: eglDestroySurface (0x5578a7a0, 0x78506710)
01-13 16:20:18.360 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/PGA: [4478] egl: eglDestroySurface (0x5578a7a0, 0x78506710) returned
01-13 16:20:18.370 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceRequest;)
01-13 16:20:18.370 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceError;)
01-13 16:20:18.370 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.webkit.WebViewClient.onReceivedError, referenced from method com.workstream.squirrel.views.Profile$Browser.onReceivedError
01-13 16:20:18.370 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10926: Landroid/webkit/WebViewClient;.onReceivedError (Landroid/webkit/WebView;Landroid/webkit/WebResourceRequest;Landroid/webkit/WebResourceError;)V
01-13 16:20:18.370 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
01-13 16:20:18.410 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/PGA: [4478] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x5578a7a0, 0x0, 0x7857b968, 0x775590e0)
01-13 16:20:18.410 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/PGA: [4478] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x5578a7a0, 0x0, 0x7857b968, 0x775590e0) returned
01-13 16:20:18.420 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
01-13 16:20:18.450 4478-4786/com.workstream.squirrel I/chromium: [INFO:simple_index_file.cc(397)] Simple Cache Index is being restored from disk.
01-13 16:20:18.460 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
01-13 16:20:18.490 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/PGA: [4478] egl: eglDestroySurface (0x5578a7a0, 0x78489620)
01-13 16:20:18.490 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel W/PGA: [4478] egl: eglDestroySurface (0x5578a7a0, 0x78489620) returned
01-13 16:20:18.870 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_CULL_FACE, assuming size 1
01-13 16:20:18.870 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_CULL_FACE, assuming size 1
01-13 16:20:18.880 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_DITHER, assuming size 1
01-13 16:20:18.880 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_DITHER, assuming size 1
01-13 16:20:18.930 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
01-13 16:20:18.980 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
01-13 16:20:19.100 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_CULL_FACE, assuming size 1
01-13 16:20:19.100 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_CULL_FACE, assuming size 1
01-13 16:20:19.110 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_DITHER, assuming size 1
01-13 16:20:19.110 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_DITHER, assuming size 1
01-13 16:20:19.220 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_CULL_FACE, assuming size 1
01-13 16:20:19.220 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_CULL_FACE, assuming size 1
01-13 16:20:19.230 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_DITHER, assuming size 1
01-13 16:20:19.230 4478-4478/com.workstream.squirrel E/PGA: PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_DITHER, assuming size 1
```

Comment: your ip not public i think

Comment: It is working fine with mobile phone.